# Check if a Excel Sheet is empty

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I have an excel workbook with multiple sheets. I need to delete the sheets which are completely empty, as my code when processing finds a blank sheet it fails.

```
os.chdir(path)
list_file=[]
for file in glob.glob("*.xlsx"):
    print(file)
    list_file.append(file)
```

I have listed all the files here available.

```
AB_list=[s for s in list_file if "India" in s]
CD_list=[s for s in list_file if "Japan" in s]
```

Then, i store the file names is list as per requirement. Now I need to delete empty sheets from those excel files before I move them to a dataframe.  Then loop through to read the files into individual dataframe.

Comment: Ok, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I know that - workbook.remove_sheet(name_of_sheet) will remove the sheet using openpyxl. But i have no idea how to determine if a sheet is empty or not.

Answer (score 2):

`ws.max_row` and `ws.max_column` should give you last used cell position. Based on that you can determine if sheet is empty. Also check if this works for you `ws.calculate_dimension()`, which should return a range.

All the functions are from `openpyxl` which you are already familiar with.

Answer (score 2):

You've tagged `openpyxl` so I assume you're using that.

```
# workbook is opened MS Exel sheet opened with openpyxl.Workbook
empty_sheets = []
for name in workbook.get_sheet_names():
    sheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name(name)
    if not sheet.columns():
        empty_sheets.append(sheet)

map(workbook.remove, empty_sheets)
```

Comment: You'll need to save the workbook to write changes back, right?

Answer (score 0):

you can easily do this with pandas which I'm using too.
    [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.empty.html)

and code looks like

```
import pandas as pd
```

`df = pd.read_csv(filename)` # 
or

`pd.read_excel(filename)` for xls file
df.empty

Comment: It does not remove empty sheets.